# why jpa not save data at a time

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa

i want save data and  check the data after call save method
but the value is not present in same request

i have two method depend each other

**the two function communcation with each other by kafka**

**the first method save the data and after save using jpa  call second method
find the recourd from database using jpa
and check the instanse using isPresent()**

but in the second method i cant find the data save
but after this request i can find data
return exciption NoSuchElement

Try out several ways like:
1-use flush and saveAndFlush
2-sleep method 10000 milsec
3-use entityManger with @Transactional

but all of them not correct

**i want showing you my two method from code:**

i have producer and consumer

and this is SaveOrder method **(first method)**:

**note :**  where in the first method have all ways i used

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void saveOrder(Long branchId,AscOrderDTO ascOrderDTO) throws Exception {
    ascOrderDTO.validation();
    if (ascOrderDTO.getId() == null) {
        ascOrderDTO.setCreationDate(Instant.now());
        ascOrderDTO.setCreatedBy(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get());
        //add user
        ascOrderDTO.setStoreId(null);
        String currentUser=SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get();
        AppUser appUser=appUserRepository.findByLogin(currentUser);
        ascOrderDTO.setAppUserId(appUser.getId());
    }
    log.debug("Request to save AscOrder : {}", ascOrderDTO);
    AscOrder ascOrder = ascOrderMapper.toEntity(ascOrderDTO);
    //send notify to branch
    if(!branchService.orderOk())
    {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("branch not accept order", "check order with branch", "branch");
    }
    ascOrder = ascOrderRepository.save(ascOrder);
    /*
     * log.debug("start sleep"); Thread.sleep(10000); log.debug("end sleep");
     */
    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
    //ascOrderRepository.flush();
    try {
        producerOrder.addOrder(branchId,ascOrder.getId(),true);
        stateMachineHandler.stateMachine(OrderEvent.EMPTY, ascOrder.getId());
        stateMachineHandler.handling(ascOrder.getId());
        //return ascOrderMapper.toDto(ascOrder);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        ascOrderRepository.delete(ascOrder);
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("cannot deliver order to Branch", "try agine", "Try!");
    }
    
}
```

**in this code go to producer :**

```
producerOrder.addOrder(branchId,ascOrder.getId(),true);
```

**and this is my producer:**

```
    public void addOrder(Long branchId, Long orderId, Boolean isAccept) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("branchId", branchId.toString());
        map.put("orderId", orderId.toString());
        map.put("isAccept", isAccept.toString());
        kafkaTemplate.send("orderone", obj.writeValueAsString(map));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**and in this code go to consumer:**

```
        kafkaTemplate.send("orderone", obj.writeValueAsString(map));
```

**this is my consumer:**

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "orderone", groupId = "groupId")
public void processAddOrder(String mapping) throws Exception {
    
      try {
          log.debug("i am in consumer add Order"); 
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); Map<String, String> result = mapper.readValue(mapping,
     HashMap.class); 

     branchService.acceptOrder(Long.parseLong(result.get("branchId")),Long.parseLong(result.get("orderId")),
      Boolean.parseBoolean(result.get("isAccept")));
      log.debug(result.toString());
     } 
      
      catch (Exception e) { 
          throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
      
     }
     
}
```

**and this code go to AcceptOrder **(second method)**  : **

```
 branchService.acceptOrder(Long.parseLong(result.get("branchId")),Long.parseLong(result.get("orderId")),
  Boolean.parseBoolean(result.get("isAccept")));
```

this is my **second method** :

```
    public AscOrderDTO acceptOrder(Long branchId, Long orderId, boolean acceptable) throws Exception {
    ascOrderRepository.flush();
    try {
        if (branchId == null || orderId == null || !acceptable) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("URl invalid query", "URL", "Check your Input");
        }

        if (!branchRepository.findById(branchId).isPresent() ||  !ascOrderRepository.findById(orderId).isPresent()) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("cannot find branch or Order", "URL", "Check your Input");
        }
        /*
         * if (acceptable) { ascOrder.setStatus(OrderStatus.PREPARING); } else {
         * ascOrder.setStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING); }   
         */
        Branch branch = branchRepository.findById(branchId).get();
        AscOrder ascOrder = ascOrderRepository.findById(orderId).get();
        ascOrder.setDiscount(50.0);
        branch.addOrders(ascOrder);
        branchRepository.save(branch);
        log.debug("///////////////////////////////Add order sucess////////////////////////////////////////////////");
        return ascOrderMapper.toDto(ascOrder);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Thread.sleep()` inside `saveOrder` makes no sense.

`processAddOrder` executes on a completely different thread, with a completely different persistence context. All the while, your transaction from `saveOrder` might still be ongoing, with none of the changes made visible to other transactions.

Try splitting `saveOrder` into a transactional method and sending the notification, making sure that the transaction ends before the event handling has a chance to take place.

(Note that this approach introduces at-most-once semantics. You have been warned)